# Is sharing vpn connection via another vpn connection possible or not?

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, connection-sharing

So I have several PCs,

I bought a vpn software(client) and it works great .

now I want to share this vpn connection among all other PCs ,

this is what I've tried:

1, I installed windows server on PC A (this software only supports windows),

2, I setup a l2tp vpn **server** on A

3, I installed the vpn software(client) aforementioned on pc A,

4，I connected the software ,and it works on pc A

5，I created a l2tp client on pc B ,and connected it to pc A(the l2tp server )

6, I thought B should now be able to access the vpn connection on A now, but no, pc B just can't access any thing on the internet like it's being blocked .

Is this by design ,or should I change something in the route table, to make it work as intended ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Some vpn services won't allow multiple clients and check for stuff like this, but otherwise it can work. If you are connecting multiple tunnels, then the easiest way is usually to bridge the two vpn adapters in windows. Otherwise yes, you need to add routes on PC A to send vpn client traffic out through the vpn interface manually